Filter a dataframe based on another dataframe
I have 2 dataframes:
df 1 =



id
name




1
name1


2
name2


3
name3


4
name4



df 2 =



id
total




1
10


1
24


1
33


2
14


2
21


3
30


4
1


4
29


4
31



I want to be able to remove items from df1 based on if the corresponding id in df2 'total' is greater than a certain value.
I tried using creating a boolean mask using DataFrame.apply which was very slow:
  def fn_should_drop(row, check_df):
    df_match = check_df.loc[check_df["id"] == row["id"]]

    max_for_id = df_match["id"].max()
    max_value = 25
    return max_for_id >= max_value

mask = df1.apply(fn_should_drop, check_df=df2, axis=1)
df_result = df1[mask]

Is there a way to achieve this using vectorization (eg np.where)?

what is your expected output?

Do you mean > or >=? Your text suggests the first (remove ... if ... "is greater than"); your code suggest the second: max_for_id >= max_value.

Here's one approach:

Select df2['id'] where df2['total'] > max_value using df.loc (boolean indexing).
For df1['id'] keep the inverse matches: ~ + Series.isin:

df_result = df1.loc[~df1['id'].isin(df2.loc[df2['total'] > max_value, 'id'])]

Output:
   id   name
1   2  name2

(change > to >= if you meant that. Your Q seems ambiguous.)
Data used
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 
        'name': {0: 'name1', 1: 'name2', 2: 'name3', 3: 'name4'}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 4}, 
         'total': {0: 10, 1: 24, 2: 33, 3: 14, 4: 21, 5: 30, 6: 1, 7: 29, 8: 31}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


IIUC, you can identify the largest value for each id with groupby aggregating with max, then use that to filter the ids you want to keep based on max_value:
max_totals = df2.groupby("id", as_index=False).max()

max_value = 25

df_result = df1[df1["id"].isin(max_totals[max_totals["total"] < max_value]["id"])]

   id   name
1   2  name2


Use a boolean mask
max_value = 20
mask = df2['total'] > max_value
answer = df1[mask]

mask is a series of type bool
>>> mask
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
8     True

You can filter values of df1 by passing in a mask, so that only values that are true in the mask are left.
>>> answer
   id   name
1   2  name2
2   3  name3


The correct answer with max_value = 20 would keep all id values. Your mask has index values from df2, whose match with index values 1,2 from df1 is arbitrary.

Merge than filter with iloc after using np.where:
merged = df1.merge(df2)
merge.iloc[np.where(merged.groupby(['id', 'name'])['total'].max().lt(25))][['id', 'name']]

If your data is sorted for sure:
df1.loc[df2.groupby('id')['total'].max().lt(25).reset_index(drop=True)]

Output:
   id   name
1   2  name2


I think that both these methods, in current form, depend on the id values being sorted. E.g., if change id 1 to 5 in both dfs, both methods select id 5 (with max_value = 25).

@ouroboros1 Check my edit.

Now it stopped working even with the original id 1, or am I missing something? Assuming you want merged there, not merge, which isn't defined.

I would do it with map if you want to go via groupby: df1[df1['id'].map(df2.groupby('id')['total'].max().lt(max_value))], though I think you don't need groupby in this case.

If id are sorted in both DataFrames, as in your example, than you can use index masking, like this:
df1[~(df2['total'] > max_value).groupby(df2['id']).agg(np.any).values]

The idea is to compare total, and then aggregate the results by grouping 'id' column, if any of value is True. Instead of np.any you can also use pd.Series.any.
Otherwise more generic approach would be to match id with isin function, like this:
df1[~df1["id"].isin(df2[df2["total"] > max_value]['id'].unique())]

Here the idea is to get your regular filtering in df2 like this: df2[df2["total"] > max_value]['id'], and then remove the duplicated 'id' by taking unique values.
